# Timezone in saving and viewing data

Tags: java, spring, datetime

I want to save a data. My database server is located here in country A but my client is in country B. Upon saving the data, I'll use the country A time but on the client side when viewing, I will use country B time. Do you have any idea to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

You can do it by :

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); // will set the UTC time zone
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone); // get calendar instance
```

now suppose you want to set for country `US` then :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone); // set the timezone to date format
```

now check the difference in both using :

```
System.out.println("UTC:     " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println("Default: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Still some problem then post.

This is basic example that how you can manage timezone and show then in `country/region` wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed zone for saving the date time (ie. UTC), then to display the date time in either country A or B shouldn't be a problem.

Do a search on `TimeZone` and mess around with it.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```